# How to implement Test Suite for Java Selenium tests

Tags: java, automated-tests, selenium-rc, test-suite

I would like to call my Selenium tests, written in Java (`@Test` annotated) from one class.

Is there option make it class as kind of ***Test Suite***,perhaps annotated appropriately?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use TestNG then you can programmatically call these test methods, for more on this - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

You can always save Selenuim tests as JUnit and run them with all your other unit tests in a single suite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to make Test Suite. You can make and run Test Suite using TestNG of your Selenium Automated Tests as below:

```
@Test
public void testTestNGProgramatically(){
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] {Test1.class, Test2.class});
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run(); 
}
```